# C++ STL sort on vectors

Tags: c++

So I'm trying to sort a vector of cards that are stored in a vector.

The vectors are `std::vector<CUE>` CUE is a class which stands for "Cards Under Evaluation" while the cards inside are `const Card*`. What I need is to sort the cards inside using the function I have created called `compareCards`.

However, I generate the following error:

> error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &,const _Elem *)' :
>   could not deduce template argument for 'const
>   std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &' from 'CUE'

The function declaration is in another file called `Table.h`, and the sort call is in `Table.cpp`. This entire thing is for a poker game I am creating, however sorting the hands has produced an error that has put me at a halt.

How can I get rid of this error while successfully sorting the hand?

Here is the relevant code:

## Sort Call:

Table.cpp

```
std::sort(cardvec.begin(), cardvec.end(), compareCards);
```

## Function Declaration:

Table.h

```
bool compareCards(const Card* c1, const Card* c2)
{   
    return c1->GetPip() < c2->GetPip(); 
}
```

## CUE.h

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include "card.h"

struct CUE
{
    CUE(void);
    ~CUE(void);
    CUE(const std::vector<const Card*>& c) : _cue(c){}
    std::vector<const Card*> _cue;
};
```

Comment: In C++ you don't need to add void to parameterless functions.

Comment: What is `Pip`? Is it sortable?

Comment: I think your callback function `compareCards` has the wrong prototype

Comment: What does GetPip() returns?

Comment: What is the point of the CUE class?

Comment: `GetPip()` returns the number value of a card, so 2-Ace.

The point of the CUE class is to store the cards under evaluation(CUE), as of right now everything works except sorting.

Comment: @AndrewB We really need an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative to Adam's answer, heres a similar solution using a more modern style (values instead of pointers, initializer lists, a lambda for the comparator, range based for loops, etc.)

You can see it running here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/96a4385814c7a4e5

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct X {
  int n;
  X(int v) : n(v) {}
};

void print(const std::vector<X>& container) {
    for (const auto& value : container) {
        std::cout << value.n << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

int main() {      
  std::vector<X> v{5, 4, 6};
  print(v);
  std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const X& a, const X& b){ return a.n < b.n; });
  print(v);
}
```

Comment: If you want to go completely modern, then you should avoid the naked loop in print. You want something like: `std::copy(std::begin(container), std::end(container), std::ostream_iterator<X>(std::cout, " "));` Of course some other changes to support that would be required as well.

Comment: @AdamBurry indeed - but I wanted to keep the example short.  Plus, the print function is really only to show that the sort worked in this demo, not part of the sort logic that the question was struggling with.

Answer (score 1):

This is a working example in the style of code that you presented (C++98):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct X {
  int n;
  X(int v) : n(v) {}
};

bool compare(const X* a, const X* b) {
  return a->n < b->n; }

int main() {
  std::vector<const X*> v;
  v.push_back(new X(5));
  v.push_back(new X(4));
  v.push_back(new X(6));

  for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
    std::cout << v[i]->n << " ";
  }
  std::cout << "\n";

  std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), compare);

  for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
    std::cout << v[i]->n << " ";
  }
  std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Output

```
5 4 6
4 5 6
```

Comment: And you've got a incredibly meaningless memory leak. Why are you using pointers at all anyway?